# geo push notifications depending on where client downloads app from

Tags: ios, location, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully set up push notifications which are sending and being received too all dev ices, However i want to now add the option of the push notification to only be sent to certain clients.

for example I would want to send clients who downloaded the application in spain a certain notification and then people who are in the uk a different notification.

Is there a way that i can add anything to my code to be able to figure this out?

I'm not to sure what to google either? Any answers better then what i already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app transmits the device token to your server, you could also send the customer's location. On your server, resolve this location to a country and store it with the device token. Then when you need to send a notification, you can look up the country for the specific device token.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me. Not sure how i could do it. Do you know of any documentation I could look at?

Comment: Have a look at the Core Location framework for grabbing the user's location https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html

Comment: Thankyou for getting back to me!

Comment: Thank you for your help i managed to do what you said in the end. works perfectly.